# Как отключить плагин в intellij idea чтоб тот не участвовал в сборке проекта

Tags: intellij-idea, плагин

В intellij idea используется плагин FindBugs-IDEA v1.0.1. Можно ли как то его отключать на время сборки jar ( но не удаляя его, тк он нужен в проекте ), иначе он сильно грузит систему и компьютером невозможно пользоваться в это время.

Answer (score 0):

Можно лишь отключить перед сборкой, а после снова включить, но каждый раз будет рестарт идеи. Необходимо нажать File->Settings, выбрать вкладку Plugins и отключай нужный тебе плагин.

Answer (score 0):

в строку  комманды maven для сборки jar нужно добавить -Dимяплагина.skip=true
,например для плагина CheckStyle нужно добавить   -Dcheckstyle.skip

Answer (score 0):

В меню File -> Settings, в открывшемся окне, слева нужно выбрать вкладку Plugins, сверху выбрать вкладку Installed. Далее снимите флаг с плагина, который хотите отключить и нажмите кнопку Apply.